# UISearchBar display issue

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

[image]

The searchbar's right edge is wider than the left, I don't know why? This is not cool.Please help me with this.Thank you very much.

Here's my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchDisplayController *strongSearchDisplayController;

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"搜索";
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT - NAVIGATIONBARHEIGHT - TABBARHEIGHT ) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
self.strongSearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: you make the search bar a header view of table view and you also showing indexes that is why it is showing you like this. If you move it out of the table view you will see that it looks ok then.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Hi, the search bar must be the header view of the tableview.So, I do not know how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: @AdeeUrRehman may be jxdwinter want something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nuxb678frz0hfq/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-12%20at%201.36.18%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: @Jageen Yeah.It's just what I want.And I put the search bar in a uiview and make the view as the header view of the talbeview.Then it's looks good at the beginning, but when I tap the search bar and then click the cancel button, it's looks the same as the above picture. :-(

Comment: @jxdwinter can you upload sample project ? it will save my time to produce problem in my environment

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman You are right! Showing header view and indexes at the same time. It's bugging me...

Comment: @Jageen but in the case of Contacts, search bar is not the part of table. It is outside the table.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to implement your search bars frame this way:

CGRectZero is the equivalent to (0,0,0,0)

Additionally it's best to add the search bar to a view. Like so:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {

UIView *searchbarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)]; //This adds a container that will hold the search bar. 
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)]; 
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
[searchbarView addSubview:self.searchBar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchbarView; //Inserts UIView into the header of self.tableView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make following:

Add top offset to your table that is equal to searchBar height:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(searchController.searchBar.frame.height, 0, 0, 0);
```

Add your searchBar to the tableView directly, not to the tableHeaderView:

```
// remove this
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

// insert this
[self.tableView addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

Please be sure that searchBar rect has correct origin (0, 0)

**Note:** It will fix your problem, but searchBar's behaviour will be a bit different from original: search bar will be visible by default, there will be no auto-hide of search bar when it's half-closed, etc.